Finding the area of a rectangle using Euclid's GCD algorithm.
I recently tried finding the area of a rectangle if the area of a square is already defined to be $side*side$. Instead of dividing the rectangle into unit squares, I tried using a kind of Euclid's Division Algorithmic approach. Here's what I did:
Take a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$ where $b>a$. Then, write $b$ as $b=an_1 + k_1$. Geometrically, the area of the squares formed should be $n_1 a^2$. Then, we write $a$ as $a=n_2 k_1 + k_2$. Now, the area of the extra squares formed is $n_2 k_1^2$. So the total area of all the squares in the figure is now $n_1 a^2 + n_2 k_1^2$. So if we repeat this, how do we prove that $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}n_{i+1} k_i ^ 2 = ab$ where $k_0 = a$?

Of course, unless one or both of the sides are irrational, the summation doesn't go till infinity. It still works, as after that point $n_i$ will be zero.

I think this can be achieved by induction on the number of steps.

Perhaps a first step might be to show that the sum $\sum n_{i+1}k_i^2$ must converge independent of the geometric interpretation.  This would mean determining bounds on $n_i,k_i$.

Yes, but how shall we go about it?

That's a really good question; obviously $n_{i+1}k_i^2$ is less than $k_{i-1}^2$ and $k_i\lt k_{i-1}$ but I'm not sure about further steps...

We must have $k_{i+2}\lt\frac 1{\sqrt 2}k_i$ though.

How did you get that? Anyway, the whole summation can be written in terms of $n_i$, $b$ and $a$, but I don't see how that helps.

So the one actual inequality should be $n_{i+3}k_{i+2}^2\le k_ik_{i+1}$.  The other arises from the fact that $k_{i+2}^2$ can at most be of size $\frac 12k_ik_{i+1}$, with equality allowed for a rational multiple.

You have to have some geometric concepts for area before you can prove anything about it. In particular, that if one set is a subset of another, then its area should be $\le$ the other's, and if two sets intersect in a set with $0$ area, then the sum of their areas is the area of the union. From this you can show that the area of the rectangle is $\ge$ every finite sum of the square areas, and therefore $\ge$ the infinite sum (which has positive terms and is bounded above by $b^2$, so it must converge). Then show that the region outside the finite unions is bounded by a square that $\to 0$.

Then how do we show that the sum converges to $a*b$?

At first sight, I had no idea for answering your question. Now, I have one : you could base your  computations on the continuous  equivalent of Euclid's algorithm i.e., the writing (of sides) under the form of "continued fractions" and the study of their so-called "convergents".

Could you explain further? I understand your idea, but don't fully understand how to use it.

How do you define what "area" is?  Why is the area of a square the the square of the sides.  Why isn't the area of a rectangle defined as side times side?  What is the area of a blob defined as (I don't mean what is the formula to find the area of a blob, I meant what are we talking about when we talk about the area of a blob [even if we have no way in the universe to figure what it is, we must have some idea of what it means]).  What does "area" mean.  We can't answer your question without that.

In fact, I have realized after having proposed "continued fractions" with their associated algorithm that in fact, there was an algorithe which is far closer to your question, with the equivalent of $gcd(a,b)=gcd(a-b,b)$ (when $a >b$). It is why I have provided such an "answer". Waiting for your comments.

Your question invites to think in terms of "induction" (this has been said in the comments) but one can think in terms of recursion ("a function calling itself..."), which is very close to induction, but with a different flavor, that one could describe in terms of "backwards induction".
In order to make a "proof of concept", I am going to present in a succinct way two recursive programs implementing the fact that, said in "plain text" :
$$\text{The area of a rectangle} \ a \times b$$
$$ \text{is the area of a rectangle} \ (a-b) \times b \ \text{augmented by}$$ $$\text{the area} \ a^2 \ \text{of the square that has been "cutted"}\tag{1}$$
in "resonence" with Euclidean algorithm, i.e.,
$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a-b,b) \ \text{when} \ \ a > b\tag{2}$$
These programs are written in Matlab.
Two steps :

When ratio $a/b$ is rational, one can consider the following program. This program begins by a "calling function" to which I have given the anonymous name "main" :
  function main
  A(53,25,0), % example : gives... 1225

  %%%%%

  function A(a,b,s) ; a,b,s resp. length, width, area "already covered by squares"
     if a==b
        s+a^2,return ; % "return" means "finished"
     end;
     if a>b
        A(a-b,b,s+b^2) ; % central action (see formula (1) above)
     else
        A(b,a,s) ; % exchange a <-> b
     end;


More generaly, when $a/b$ isn't a rational number (or if we don't know it), one must add a fourth parameter in order to pilot the recursion "depth". This is done in the following program with function $A(a,b,s)$ replaced by $A(a,b,s,d)$ where parameter $d = depth$ is arbitrarily limited to a maximum value of $30$ :
  function main
  e=exp(1);A(pi,e,0,0), % see comments below

  %%%%%

  function A(a,b,s,d)
     if a==b || d==30 ; % double bar means "or"
        s+a^2,return; 
     end;
     if a>b
        A(a-b,b,s+b^2,d+1) ; case of depth increase
     else
        A(b,a,s,d); 
    end;



For the given irrational values $a=\pi, \ b=e$(with $a/b$ irrational itself...), with recursivity depth $d=30$, we obtain the approximate result :
$$\pi \times e \approx 
 8.539738...$$
whereas the exact value is $8.539734...$. Five exact decimals... not bad.
Let us insist on the fact that the second program improves (and replaces) the first one.
One can make an objection about the arbitrary chosen limit depth $30$. In fact, conceptualy, nothing prevents to replace $30$ by higher and higher limit depth values, in order to obtain results arbitrarily close to the exact value.
Remarks :

Instead of Matlab, I could have used  a pseudo-language, but it would have been almost the same instructions.

Some "geeks" say that they don't use recursion because it leads to longer execution time ; this is far from true ; here for example, the second program gives its result in $3$ milliseconds on my slow PC. This is also not fair if you consider developing/debugging time, which can be shorter for recursive programs because you implement in a clear way the different properties described for example when there are underlying mathematical formulas. For example, it is easy to write a recursive program giving the value of binomial coefficients by placing $C(n,p)=C(n-1,p)+C(n-1,p-1)$ at the center of your program, and stop the recursive calls when $n=0$ and $n=p$.



I like your answer, but now I am really interested in your continued fractions idea. How should we try to fit that in this algorithm?

I am going to give you an answer. Meanwhile, I want also to add a graphical representation to the previous answer.
