Area of Parallelogram is Well Defined
EDIT: Reframed the question for clarity
EDIT: Proved that $A$ is well defined on Rectangles.
Let's say I have a parallelogram $ABCD$. I label $AB$ with $a$ and its corresponding height $h_{1}$ and I label $BC$ with $b$ and its corresponding height $h_{2}$. I am given the following facts/postulates/axioms:

All polygons have an Area
If polygon $A$ is comprised of almost disjoint polygon $B$ and polygon $C$ then the area of $A$ is the sum of the area of $B$ and $C$.
Congruent shapes share the same area
The area of a square with sidelength $S$ is $S^{2}$

If we ignore axioms 4, it is clear that Axioms 1-3 say the Area function is a function defined as follows:
$$
A:\mathbb{P}\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \\ 
$$
where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of polygons in a euclidean space, and where $A$ satisfies axioms 1-3. A trivial example for $A$ is setting $A$ to be the 0 function. An example of a function that doesn't work is if $A$ is defined implicitly by setting the area of a square to $2S$ given that the side length is $S$ then $A$ is not well defined: take a rectangle that is $2S\times S$ one can show $A$ can both give an area of $4S$ and $0$ depending on how one decomposes the rectangle. As such it is clear that not just any definition of $A$ can work. Axiom 4 implicitly defines $A$ by setting the area of a square to be $S^{2}$. My question is why does this implicit definition of $A$ satisfy axioms 1-3 and is well-defined.
The motivation for this question is because the area of ABCD can be $ah_{1}$ or $bh_{2}$ and it is not clear why the two values would have to be equal.
EDIT:
I was asked to show that $A$ defined by axiom 4 is consisted to the space of squares. I believe I have a proof below:
$A$ maps squares to $S^{2}$ if and only if $A$ maps rectangles to $lw$ where $l$ and $w$ are the corresponding side lengths. If we then show $A$ is well defined on the space of rectangles, it would automatically be well defined on the space of squares. Lemma 1.1 shows any decomposition of a rectangle into an almost disjoint finite decomposition is well defined. Using this lemma, I claim that if $R$ is a rectangle that is decomposed into a countably infinite family of almost disjoint rectangles then $A(R)$ is well defined. Assume
$$
R=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}R_{i}
$$
In particular
$$
R\supset \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}R_{i}
$$
so the linked lemma says $A(R)\geq \sum_{i=1}^{n}A(R_{i})$. Denote
$$ S_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}A(R_{i})$$
Then $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n}<A(R)$. As it is monotone increasing and bounded $S_{n}\to S$ has a limit.
Consider then $R\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}R_{i}$. This region must be rectalinear and thus can be decomposed into finitely many rectangles.
$$
R\backslash \bigcup_{i=1}^{n}R_{i} = \bigcup_{j=1}^{k}\tilde{R_{j}}=\bigcup_{i=n+1}^{\infty}R_{i}
$$
This means that $(S-S_{n})=\sum_{j=1}^{k}A(\tilde{R_{j}})$. As $n\to \infty$ that means that $(S-S_{n})$ goes to $0$, which means that $\sum_{j=1}^{k}A(\tilde{R_{j}})$. In otherwords each finite decomposition of the rectalinear shape has its area decrease to 0 as $n$ increases.
$A(R)= S_{n}+\sum_{i=1}^{k}A(\tilde{R_{j}})$ meaning $\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{n}=A(R)$.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In an answer to a much earlier question it is shown (using axioms 1, 2, and 3 implicitly) that the areas of two parallelograms with the same base and the same altitude to that base are equal.
(A similar proof is given in another answer to this question. A slightly different proof is given in Euclid's Elements Book I Proposition 35 using the same notions.)
This is true even if one parallelogram happens to be a rectangle.
Therefore, since a triangle has exactly half the area of at least one parallelogram with the same base and the same altitude (by joining the triangle to a congruent triangle sharing one side as shown in a figure below), a triangle has exactly half the area of a rectangle of the same base and altitude.
Note that at this point we have not said what the areas of any of these figures are. We used axiom 1 to infer that the areas are all defined, and we used axioms 2 and 3 to show that areas of certain pairs of polygons are equal or that one is twice another.

I will use the fact that triangles with equal angles are similar
(that is, the sides of one triangle are proportional to the corresponding sides of the other). This is proved in Euclid Book VI Proposition 4 using equal angles to show parallel lines and using the Intercept Theorem (Euclid Book VI Proposition 2, also proved in another math.stackexchange answer).
The Intercept Theorem, in turn, uses two facts about areas: the equal areas of two triangles on the same base with the same altitude (due to the facts about parallelograms cited above) and the areas of two triangles with the same altitude are in proportion to the lengths of their bases (Euclid Book VI Proposition 1). Book VI Proposition 1 in turn also uses the equal areas of triangles with equal bases and altitudes, and it applies Eudoxus's theory of proportions to triangles built up by adding together triangles of equal areas. In other words, this proposition is based on axioms 1, 2, and 3 from the question along with a method similar to the method of limits used with real numbers. Since we are willing to assign numbers to lengths and areas, a similar proof could be written using limits rather than Eudoxus's theory.

Now consider the figure below.

For triangle $\triangle ABC$ or parallelogram $ABA'C,$ we drop perpendiculars from $B$ and $C$ to points $D$ and $E$ on the (possibly extended) sides $AC$ and $AB,$ respectively.
Denote the side lengths and altitudes $\lvert AC\rvert = b,$ $\lvert BD\rvert = h_b,$
$\lvert AB\rvert = c,$ and $\lvert CE\rvert = h_c.$
Right triangles $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ACE$ are similar, and therefore
$$ \frac{h_b}{c} = \frac{h_c}{b}. $$
Cross-multiplying, we have
$$ b h_b = c h_c. $$
This shows that the product of the altitude and base of a parallelogram is the same no matter which side is chosen as the base.
(In this case we have chosen two sides that meet at an acute angle, but since
$\lvert AC\rvert = \lvert A'C\rvert$ the conclusion is also true for two sides that meet at an obtuse angle; and of course if the angle is a right angle, the altitude on each base is simply the adjacent side.)
Likewise the product of the altitude and base of a triangle is the same using either side as a base when two sides meet at an acute angle. But every triangle has at least two acute angles; assuming (without loss of generality) that $b$ is a side of the triangle between two vertices whose angles are acute, we then have
$b h_b = c h_c$ and $a h_a = b h_b$
(since the angles between sides $b$ and $c$ and between sides $a$ and $b$ are both acute) and therefore $a h_a = c h_c.$ That is, the product of the base and altitude of the triangle is independent of which side is chosen as the base.
Since triangles $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle A'BC$ are congruent, we can also conclude that the area of the triangle $\triangle ABC$ is half the area of the parallelogram $ABA'C,$ which has the same base ($AB$) and same altitude ($CE$).

Any polygon can be dissected into triangles. Of course there are multiple ways to dissect any polygon (even a triangle!) into triangles, but if we take any two such dissections, the intersection of the interiors of any pair of triangles, one from one dissection and one from the other, is either the interior of a convex polygon or empty, so two dissections into triangles determine a single dissection into convex polygons which are in turn dissections of the triangles, so both dissections have the same total area as the single dissection into convex polygons. The area of a polygon is therefore independent of how we dissect it into triangles; that is, if we know a general way to find the area of a triangle we can use axioms 1, 2, and 3 to measure the area of any polygon

Now suppose $ab = a'b'$ for four numbers $a, b, a', b'.$ Without loss of generality, label the numbers so that $b'$ is the greatest of the four.
Construct a rectangle $ABCD$ with sides
$\lvert AB\rvert = a$ and $\lvert AD\rvert = b$
as shown in  the figure below.

Now put $D'$ on side $CD$ (or its extension past $C,$ as shown) so that
$\lvert AD'\rvert = b',$ and let $\triangle ABB'$ be a triangle outside the rectangle such that $\angle AB'B$ is a right angle and
$\lvert AB'\rvert = a'.$
From $ab = a'b'$ we find that
$$ \frac{b'}{b} = \frac{a}{a'} $$
and therefore the right triangles $\triangle ADD'$ and $\triangle AB'B$ are similar.
A little angle-chasing then shows that $B'B$ is parallel to $AD'.$
Extend $B'B$ as necessary and drop a perpendicular from $D'$ to point $C'$ on the line $B'B.$ Then $AB'C'D'$ is a rectangle with sides
$\lvert AB'\rvert = a'$ and $\lvert AD'\rvert = b'.$
Parallelogram $ABPD'$ has the same base $a$ and the same altitude $b$ as rectangle $ABCD,$ so the two figures have the same area.
But parallelogram $ABPD'$ also has the same base $b'$ and the same altitude $a'$ as rectangle $AB'C'D',$ so the two figures have the same area.
It follows that the two rectangles $ABCD$ and $AB'C'D'$ have the same area.
Since two rectangles have the same area whenever the products of their sides are equal, the area of a rectangle is a function of the product of its sides.
In other words, the area of a rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$ is $f(ab)$ for some function $f.$
The area of a triangle of altitude $a$ and base $b$ is $\frac12 f(ab).$

The question remains, what kind of function is $f$?
For any side lengths $a$ and $b$ and any positive integers $m$ and $n$ we can construct a rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$ and a rectangle of sides $\frac nm a$ and $b$ that can be dissected into sets of $m$ and $n$ rectangles of sides $\frac 1m a$ and $b,$ respectively.
Therefore if we choose any reference rectangle of sides $a$ and $b,$ any rectangle whose product of sides is a rational multiple of $ab$ has area proportional to the product of its sides.
That is, restricted to a set of commensurate numbers (numbers related by rational ratios), $f$ is simply multiplication by a constant of proportionality.
Moreover, $f$ is an increasing function, because given any two numbers you can factor them as $ab$ and $ab'$ with $b < b'$ and show a rectangle of sides $a$ and $b'$ that contains a rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$ plus another rectangle of positive area.
We can take these facts and an argument via limits (or by the principle of exhaustion, which is an ancient kind of argument via limits) to conclude that $f$ is generally multiplication by a constant of proportionality.
But that's all we can conclude. We cannot show what the constant of proportionality is. In fact, you can choose any constant of proportionality and obtain a perfectly consistent notion of area, just as you can choose (in real life) to measure area in square meters or square centimeters and have equally valid results either way, although one measurement will be consistently $10000$ times the other.

To sum up, the conventional measurement of area used the fact that the area of a rectangle is the product of the sides of the rectangle multiplied by a fixed constant of proportionality, and we choose the constant to be $1.$
Therefore the area of a rectangle of sides $a$ and $b$ is simply $ab$
and the area of a triangle of altitude $a$ and base $b$ is $\frac12 ab.$
If we have a square of side $s,$ we treat it as a rectangle of sides $a=s$ and $b=s$ and its area is $s^2.$
But we could have chosen the constant of proportionality $2.$ Then the area of a triangle of altitude $a$ and base $b$ would be $ab$ and the area of a square of side $s$ would be $2s^2.$ Or we could have chosen the constant $\frac1\pi,$ in which case the triangle would have area $\frac1\pi ab,$ the square would have area $\frac1\pi s^2,$
and a circle of radius $r$ would have area $r^2.$
It appears that in practice, the convenience of using $ab$ as the area of a rectangle outweighs the convenience of having $ab$ as the area of a triangle or $r^2$ as the area of a circle, so we use the constant $1.$ I don't think there's really any deeper reason for that choice.
In that sense, axiom 4 is less fundamental than axioms 1, 2, or 3,
since it can be partially modified (by inserting a different constant) without invalidating the arguments above, but modifications to the other axioms are not so easily and so harmlessly made.
We might be able to weaken axiom 1 to state only that all triangles have area, but the argument about dissections then becomes more complicated.

About the use of Eudoxus's proportions or limits: If we are to develop a theory of area that allows measurements of two areas whose ratio is irrational, I don't see any alternative to using some kind of limit argument at some point in the argument.
As long as we're using limits, we could establish directly that the area of a square of side $s$ is proportional to $s^2$ by constructing a sequence of squares with sides slightly larger and slightly smaller than $s$ dissected into small squares with rational sides. But I find the method above more satisfying for some reason.

But the OP didn’t want to use similarity (at least in a previous version of the question) because proofs of similarity depended on area of triangle or parallelogram, or something like that.

@Pranay Digging back into the edit history, I see that notion. I don't know which proof OP referred to, but there is a proof without using area measurement, so I've included a note about that.

@AlexRavsky Yes, thank you!

@DavidK thank you for the detailed response! I had a few extra questions: you mention that different dissections into triangles yield a single dissection into polygons to claim that the area of a polygon is independent of how one dissects into triangles; wouldn't axioms 1-3 imply that automatically? I did not understand that part. Along that line, your arguments convinced me that if an area function that satisfies axioms 1-4 exists, it has to set the area of a rectangle to ab. I am not entirely convinced that such a function has to exist at all though.

@DavidK Also, in the proof of AA similarity you linked, I believe he uses the intercept theorem; he claims that the sides of the triangle are proportional because AC is parallel to FE. That proof relies on the area of the triangle being defined as proportional to base times height.

I debated whether to write about the dissection of the polygon. Axiom 1 implies a function from each polygon to its area, but I'm not aware of a way to prove that axiom from more fundamental facts. I think you're probably right that the function does not need to exist.

Your point about the Intercept Theorem is well put. I was wrong to say in an earlier version of the answer that the proportionality of similar triangles did not rely on area. It does use area measurement, but it needs only axioms 1, 2, and 3 along with a notion equivalent to limits in order to deal with irrational numbers. I have rearranged and enlarged the answer somewhat to account for this.

@DavidK As far as I remember (but I didn't check) Intercept Theorem can also be proved without areas.

@Intelligentipauca Actually, I think you're right. For triangles where one corresponding pair of sides are commensurate, by drawing certain sets of lines parallel to the three sides you can dissect the triangles into smaller triangles, all congruent, proving the other sides are in the same ratio. Then apply some form of limits for triangles whose sides are not commensurate. This is on one of the wikis, though I forget which.

A related question: if we can't measure area (because the area function doesn't exist), what do we lose from plane geometry? Note that some of the things we like to prove by using area might also be proved without it.

@DavidK You don't need an axiom of existence to define areas. See Hilbert's treatise, for instance.

Consider two parallelograms with the same base $(AB)$
And opposite edges of both parallelograms lie on the same line.  $CD$ and $EF$ both lie on line $L.$

Claim: $ABDC$ and $ABFE$ have the same area.
$\triangle ACE \cong \triangle BDF$
The area of each parallelogram is the area of ABFC less the appropriate triangle.
The length of the base and distance to the opposite side (h) determines the area of the triangle, regardless of the skewness of the parallelogram.

Thank you for your answer! However, I am aware that using the axioms you can show that these two parallelograms are equal and then furthermore equal to a rectangle with the the corresponding base and heights as side lengths. My issue stems more from the fact that if you were to use a different base, in this case $CA$ you will get a different rectangle. Rules 1,2,3 say those two rectangles have the same Area but why does the area formula necessarily follow those rules?

I guess another way to phrase my question is why is fact 4 consistent with the other facts: why does that definition for the area of a square (or a rectangle for that matter) ensure areas of other polygons are unique?

Here's a question that may help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4973547/1385195
